# What is the web-app to create your own json api?

Tags: web-apps, api, json

Last year I used a real simple web-app with my students so they would not have to drop their hard coded JSON objects inside the codebase of their JavaScript application.

Instead they could drop it into a textbox type of UI on this site and click the button and it would instantly provide an API endpoint and this way I could teach them how to create an API request to their data and it is super frustrating that I have since cleared my caching and browser history so I cannot find the name of the url.

It's a very humble simple site, its not jsonplaceholder, I am not asking for a JSON formatter. It has a grey background with a textbox where you just drop the JSON code and click the button and it gives you a working API endpoint that you can visit and see your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's so annoying that after I posted this question, I vaguely recalled the name and found it. It's weird how having to describe something you are looking for in written text helps with memory brain cells.

For anyone interested in this elegant and humble application, its called:
http://myjson.com/